# VBA MS-Access For Loop Not Incrementing

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

Sincerely in the dark. My Code:

```
Public Property Get rowCount() As Integer
rowCount = Counter
End Property

Public Property Let rowCount(ByRef inte As Integer)
 Counter = inte
 End Property

Private Sub Form_Timer() 'Timer
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Caption As Field, Form As Field, Count As Integer, holder As Integer, item As String
Dim strForms() As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("MainMenu", dbOpenDynaset)

ReDim strForms(1 To rs.RecordCount())
If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
  For c = 1 To rs.RecordCount() Step 1 '!!!THIS IS THE PROBLEM!!!
   MsgBox CStr(c)
   MsgBox rs("Caption")
   strForms(c) = rs("Caption")
   rs.MoveNext
   MsgBox rs("Caption")
  Next c
End If
rowCount = 1
holder = rowCount()
If holder <= rs.RecordCount() Then
 Me.Command10.Caption = strForms(holder)
 rowCount = holder + 1
Else
 rowCount = 1
 Me.Command10.Caption = strForms(holder)
End If

End Sub
```

I added all those message boxes in my effort to debug. All I need is that counter to go up. No idea why it is not. Why will this thing not increment?!

Comment: No it is not, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Also, if the dataset was empty it would not even enter the for loop.

Comment: the `RecordCount` property is not accurate when an RS is first built, so your loop counter is never going to be correct.  Better to do the `Do Until Rs.EOF` method.  The count is not accurate because of the overhead to drag them to the client to count them - Access does the same thing on a local RS not showing the accurate RecordCount until you scroll to the end of the View/Query/View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use rs.MoveFirst, rs.MoveNext and rs.EOF to check for end of records. The following VBA will do what you want.

```
'Open up a recordset on our table
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("MyTable", dbOpenDynaset)

'Did we find any records?
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

    'Move to first record
    rs.MoveFirst

    'Iterate through each record
    Do

        'Do stuff with the currentrecord
        MsgBox ("Next record ID is: " + CStr(rs("ID")))

        'Move to next record
        rs.MoveNext

        'Exit when we hit the end of the recordset
    Loop While rs.EOF <> True

End If

'Close the recordset
rs.Close
```

Comment: Your answer was much clearer than mine, sir.. I learned something.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the RecordCount property might be the problem.

It essesntially just counts the number of times rs.MoveNext had been called.

Try switching the code to a loop like this:

```
Dim L As Long
Do Until rs.EOF
    L = L + 1
    MsgBox rs.RecordCount
    MsgBox L
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Access Recordsets aren't as easy as .NET DataTables but they've been around a lot longer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208624(v=office.12).aspx